# Elasticsearch NumberFormatException when running two consecutive java tests

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch, numberformatexception, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two test in a class, each of them containing the following query:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery()).withFilter(rangeFilter("publishDate").lt(date)).build();
```

In one of the tests, the number of the results `elasticsearchTemplate.count(searchQuery, Article.class)`, in the other one the returned values are verified `elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery,Article.class)`

If I run any of these two tests separately, the tests always pass, everything seems to work perfectly.
**If I run both of the two tests consequently**, one after the other, **the first one passes, the other one fails** with a *SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase ... nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.396Z"]...*

It's even more strange, that this behavior appears just when a rangefilter for publishDate (having type: *FieldType.Date*) is applied. When other similar queries with boolFilter, termFilter etc are applied consequently, all the tests pass.

Also, if I run these two queries inside the same method: no exception is thrown.

I thought that an improper cache initialization/cleanup might cause the behavior... but still, why does not happen to the other queries as well?

Also, in the @After method of the class I delete all the indexes (elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Article.class)), and in the @Before method I do/redo bulk indexing and refresh.

Am I on the wrong path? What am I missing here?

The full stack trace:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[jCBsPj2yR3qkX6HxN_xr4w][articles][0]: SearchParseException[[articles][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match_all":{}},"post_filter":{"range":{"publishDate":{"from":null,"to":"2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z"]; }{[jCBsPj2yR3qkX6HxN_xr4w][articles][1]: SearchParseException[[articles][1]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match_all":{}},"post_filter":{"range":{"publishDate":{"from":null,"to":"2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z"]; }{[jCBsPj2yR3qkX6HxN_xr4w][articles][2]: SearchParseException[[articles][2]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match_all":{}},"post_filter":{"range":{"publishDate":{"from":null,"to":"2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z"]; }{[jCBsPj2yR3qkX6HxN_xr4w][articles][3]: SearchParseException[[articles][3]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match_all":{}},"post_filter":{"range":{"publishDate":{"from":null,"to":"2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z"]; }{[jCBsPj2yR3qkX6HxN_xr4w][articles][4]: SearchParseException[[articles][4]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match_all":{}},"post_filter":{"range":{"publishDate":{"from":null,"to":"2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2015-02-01T00:02:02.676Z"]; }
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:238)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:184)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The mapping for the article index:

```
@Document(indexName = "articles", type = "article", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1", indexStoreType = "memory")
public class Article {
@Id
private Long id;
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
private String title;
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
private String text;
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
private String author;
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
private Date publishDate;
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
private Date lastModificationDate;
....
}
```

Comment: When building the `rangeFilter()` on `publishDate`, where does the `date` variable come from in `lt(date)`? Is it a global variable that can be modified at several places? Can you share some insights on that please?

Comment: I first initialize the calendar instance, then I just get calendar.getTime(). And I'm doing this inside each of the tests.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace please?

Comment: Sure. I've just attached it.

Comment: Can you also share the mapping of your `articles` index, please? It looks like `publishDate` is of `number` type instead of `date`.

Comment: It's `date`. But even in case of a `number` type... i would expect for the exception to be thrown all the time, and not only when I run two of them, consequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception complains about a `NumberFormatException`, you should try sending the date as a long (instead of a Date object) since this is how dates are stored internally. See I'm calling `date.getTime()` in the code below:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withFilter(rangeFilter("publishDate").lt(date.getTime())).build();
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this has solved the problem. :) But I still don't understand why did the test pass each time when it was running alone...

Comment: It might have something to do with how `@After` and `@Before` are run between the two test runs. Probably that the index is not probably created during the second test.

Comment: In `@Before` I create some indexQueries, I do bulk indexing `elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(queries)`, and finally a refresh (`elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Article.class, true)`). In the `@After` I just delete them all (`elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Article.class)`).

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution too.

In `@Before` method I had no explicit mapping applied, which means that the `@Field` annotations from the `Article` index were not considered. Practically, a default mapping was used.

By adding an explicit mapping:

```
elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Article.class)
```

the `type` for `publishDate` is taken from the index definition:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
private Date publishDate;
```

In this way all the tests pass, whether running them each individually or all of them sequentially.

Also, the `rangeFilter`parameter works fine with the initial `date type` too. (Sure, it works with `long type` as well.)